# Getting many audio on the current browser tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm having trouble getting audio on the current browser tab using javascript. I don't know if there's a way to get continuous audio responses back to the system using the API. Thank you. I tried with

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia () function onAccessApproved(stream){
     const options = {
         audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
         videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
         mimeType: "video/webm", // Changed to a valid MIME type
     };
     recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

     recorder.ondataavailable = function(event){
         let recordedBlob = event.data
         let url = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob)

         let a = document.createElement("a");

         a.style.display = "none";
         a.href = url;

         // Generate a random number from 1 to 1000
         var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;

         // Get the current time to generate part of the random name
         var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

         // Generate random names by combining random numbers and times
         var random_name = "screen-recording_" + random_number + "_" + timestamp + ".webm";

         // Set value for download attribute
         a.download = random_name;

         // a.download = "screen-recording.webm"; // Changed to match the MIME type
         document.body.appendChild(a)
        
         a.click();

         document.body.removeChild(a);

         URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     }
    

     recorder.start(1000);
    
}
```

Every 1 second, the video will be downloaded once, but the card with the first video can be opened and the other videos will have an error.